# Script send hotkey to OBS studio at specific time

Tags: hotkeys

I have OBS studio 20.1 64bit windows7. I have numerous scenes in OBS studio. I have assigned hotkeys to each one. Is there a way to write a script sending a specific hotkey to OBS studio at a specific time? I am trying to have scenes display at a specific time based on the system clock.

So for purposes of an example, one scene of mine “Video5 scene” has hotkey of control+numpad5. I want this hotkey to be sent to obs at 6:15PM EST to the scene will display at that time.

I am not good with coding. So if someone could provide me with a line of code to do the above I would be greatly appreciative

Comment: Google autohotkey. Google before posting here.

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I did search google. I downloaded ahk but none of the scripts I write work. for instance this script which I got off this website which should hit a hotkey of control numpad3 at the specified time does not work. I get an error "error target label does not exist" line 003. AHK Here is the code I am using for this which does not work even for this simple task

Comment: #Persistent
SetTimer, CheckTime, 60000 ;check time every minute
return   

CheckTime
if (A_hour . A_Min=0301) or (A_Hour . A_Min=1101) 
Send ^{Numpad3}
Return

Comment: Another forum answer on this topic provides a basic test script which the user says can be used to make sure the commands are getting to OBS. But when this is put into a ahk script for me and I run it nothing happens. I do have a scene set for control numpad3. again any help I would be very greatful. #o::
controlSend,, ^{Numpad3},ahk_class Qt5QWindowIcon
return

Comment: All that prior work you did sounds good. Please post some actual code in your question. Without showing any code or research effort in your question it looks like you didn't do any.

Comment: Don't post code as comments, update your question

Comment: Thanks for your editorial advice on posting to forums